# Same index file, same browser (IE9) but different display when accessing from internet than direct from local disk

Tags: css, http, protocols

Accessing the same index.html file in the same browser gives different views depending from where it is accessed. The only difference visible is on the source properties.
Access from hard disk gives: File Protocol.
Access from internet server gives HTTP Protocol.

The difference is from a css style but the code is included in the index.html file and not in a separate css file.
Any ideas why? Just asking because my web page preview software is showing it wrong as well.

The following screen shot displays the 2 versions of layout in the same IExplorer including the properties

[screen shot](http://stetson.co.nz/ie_display.jpg)

Style in head

```
table.b_round { width:480px;
                height:150px;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                font-size:11pt;
              }

div.round{
margin:20px;
width:480px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;border:2px solid #331100;background-color:#none; }
#lightbox{
background-color:#ffeebb;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
border-right: 0px solid #fff;
}
```

Code in body

```
<div class="round">
<table class="b_round">
<tr>
  <td style="width:220px;"> 
    Friday<br>24. April 2015
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2" style="border-left:solid 2px #331100;">
    <a href="images/rocknroll_all_stars-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="">
      <img src="images/rocknroll_all_stars-1_s.jpg" rel="lightbox" width="180" height="120" border="0"  class="opac" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td  style="border-top:solid 2px #331100;" >
    <a href="http://www.rocknrollallstars.net" target="_blank"
      title="http://www.rocknrollallstars.net"><b>The Rock'n'Roll<br> All Stars</b></a>
  </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Somehow the style is only processed from the url address and not from the local disk. Could it be a problem with the "Internet Option" settings?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the code which is displayed differntly? Maybe a screenshot would also help

Comment: Screenshots showing the exact differences, as well as sample code, will help a lot here.

Comment: Yes, IE is capable of behaving differently for different URLS. Compatibility mode for one site, edge mode for another, etc. Javascript enabled for trusted sites and disabled for others. Anything is possible!